# How to deal with $\nabla(\delta\Psi)$ in functional derivatives?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, functional-derivatives

I am trying to compute the functional derivative of the following functional

$$F[\Psi]=\int{}d^nx\Psi{}e^{(\nabla\Psi)^2}.$$

What I have tried up till now is the following

$$F[\Psi+\delta\Psi]=\int{}d^nx(\Psi{}+\delta\Psi)e^{(\nabla(\Psi+\delta\Psi))^2},$$

and expanding it in first order of $\delta\Psi$ I have obtained

$$F[\Psi+\delta\Psi]-F[\Psi]=\int{}d^nxe^{(\nabla\Psi)^2}(2\Psi\nabla\Psi\nabla(\delta\Psi)+\delta\Psi).$$

What I don't know is how to deal with $\nabla(\delta\Psi)$ in order to be able to cast the above equation in this form

$$F[\Psi+\delta\Psi]-F[\Psi]=\int{}d^nx\frac{\delta{}F[\Psi]}{\delta\Psi}\delta\Psi.$$

Comment: integrating by part and the boundary condtion $\delta\Psi(\pm \infty)=0$ seems to be the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Frederic, you should integrate the

$$ \int d^n x \: \alpha^a(x) \cdot \nabla_a \delta \Psi $$

term (with whatever $\alpha$ should be) by parts using the Ostrogradsky-Gauss theorem and the boundary condition $\delta \Psi (\infty) \rightarrow 0$. But Euler and Lagrange have already done it for you, so you can just use the formula for an arbitrary functional

$$ S[\Psi, \nabla \Psi, \nabla^2 \Psi, ...] = \int d^n x \cdot L \left( \Psi(x), \, \nabla \Psi (x), \, \nabla^2 \Psi(x), \, ... \right). $$

Its variation with respect to $\Psi$ is called the Euler-Lagrange derivative:

$$ \delta S = \int d^n x \cdot \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \Psi} - \nabla_a \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\nabla_a \Psi)} + \frac{1}{2!} \nabla_a \nabla_b \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\nabla_a \nabla_b \Psi)} - \: ... \right) \delta \Psi. $$

In your case $F[\Psi]$ depends only on $\Psi$ and $\nabla \Psi$ (and not on higher-order derivatives), so just use the first two terms in the previous integral.